# Unit testing automapper

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, automapper

I am having trouble getting automapper to work in my unit test. I am injecting the mapping engine, and this works fine in code, but not in the test. here is my test set up and test. I am using Moq to mock the mapping engine.

```
private static IDbContext Context { get; set; }
private static Mock<IMappingEngine> Mapper { get; set; }
private static Guid MenuId { get; set; }

private static Guid menuItem1Id { get; set; }
private static Guid menuItem2Id { get; set; }
private static Guid menuItem3Id { get; set; }

[ClassInitialize]
public static void SetUp(TestContext context)
{
    MenuId = Guid.NewGuid();
    Context = new TestDbContext();

    menuItem1Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    menuItem2Id = Guid.NewGuid();
    menuItem3Id = Guid.NewGuid();

    var contentPage1 = new ContentPage { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ActionName = "ActionName1", ControllerName = "ControllerName1", MenuItemId = menuItem1Id };
    var contentPage2 = new ContentPage { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ActionName = "ActionName2", ControllerName = "ControllerName2", MenuItemId = menuItem2Id };
    var contentPage3 = new ContentPage { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), ActionName = "ActionName3", ControllerName = "ControllerName3", MenuItemId = menuItem3Id };

    var menuItem1 = new MenuItem { Id = menuItem1Id, MenuId = MenuId, DisplayName = "MenuItem1", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ContentPage = contentPage1 };
    var menuItem2 = new MenuItem { Id = menuItem1Id, MenuId = MenuId, DisplayName = "MenuItem2", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ContentPage = contentPage2 };
    var menuItem3 = new MenuItem { Id = menuItem1Id, MenuId = MenuId, DisplayName = "MenuItem3", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ContentPage = contentPage3 };

    var menu = new Models.Menu { Id = MenuId, Name = "TestMenu", SiteId = Guid.NewGuid(), MenuItems = new List<MenuItem> { menuItem1, menuItem2, menuItem3 } };

    Context.Menus.Add(menu);
    Context.MenuItems.Add(menuItem1);
    Context.MenuItems.Add(menuItem2);
    Context.MenuItems.Add(menuItem3);

    var menuItemQueryResult = new List<MenuItemQueryResult>
    {
        new MenuItemQueryResult { Id = menuItem1Id, DisplayName = "MenuItem1", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ActionName = "ActionName1", ControllerName = "ControllerName1" },
        new MenuItemQueryResult { Id = menuItem1Id, DisplayName = "MenuItem2", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ActionName = "ActionName2", ControllerName = "ControllerName2" },
        new MenuItemQueryResult { Id = menuItem1Id, DisplayName = "MenuItem3", ExternalUrl = null, Target = Target._self, Active = true, ActionName = "ActionName3", ControllerName = "ControllerName3" }
    };

    Mapper = new Mock<IMappingEngine>();

    Mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<IEnumerable<MenuItem>, IEnumerable<MenuItemQueryResult>>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<MenuItem>>()))
                        .Returns(menuItemQueryResult);
}

[TestMethod]
public void Retrieve_RequestMenu_QueryResultReturned()
{
    var handler = new MenuQueryHandler(Context, Mapper.Object);
    var query = new MenuQuery("TestMenu");
    var result = handler.Retrieve(query);
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsInstanceOfType(result, typeof(MenuQueryResult));

    var item = result.FirstOrDefault(r => r.Id == menuItem1Id);
    Assert.IsNotNull(item);
}
```

And here is what I am testing:

```
public class MenuQueryHandler : IQueryHandler<MenuQuery, MenuQueryResult>
{
    private IDbContext Context { get; set; }
    private IMappingEngine Mapper { get; set; }

    public MenuQueryHandler(IDbContext context, IMappingEngine mapper)
    {
        Context = context;
        Mapper = mapper;
    }

    public MenuQueryResult Retrieve(MenuQuery query)
    {
        Ensure.Argument.Is(query != null);
        Ensure.Argument.IsNot(query.MenuName == string.Empty);

        // Create the view model query result
        var result = new List<MenuItemQueryResult>();

        // Pull the required item from the cont.ext
        var menuItems = Context.MenuItems.Include(m => m.ContentPage).ToList();

        Mapper.Map(menuItems, result);

        return new MenuQueryResult(result);

    }
}
```

The test runs, but the mapping never occurs.

Comment: Don't mock AutoMapper. I never, ever do.

Comment: You are using the actual instance of automapper in tests? What I was trying to accomplish was injecting the automapper engine (IMappingEngine). If I inject it, I need an instance for testing. You are saying don't inject IMappingEngine?

Comment: Yep. Even if you inject the IMappingEngine, I don't mock it. I use the real thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You aren't mocking the method you're actually calling. The method you're testing calls this method:

   ```
   TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination);
   ```

   This overload of `Map` takes an existing `destination` object and maps into it.

   In your test, you're mocking the overload of `Map` that returns a *new* instance of `TDestination`:

   ```
   TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination(TSource source);
   ```

   Note that the one you're mocking takes one parameter and the one you're actually calling takes two.
2. Your `Setup` method sets up a fake mapping between `IEnumerable<MenuItem>` and `IEnumerable<MenuItemQueryResult>`. In your test, you're actually calling `Map` with a `List<MenuItem>` and a `List<MenuItemQueryResult>`.

   In actual usage, AutoMapper is going to handle the `List` to `List` mapping for your using the `IEnumerable` mapping. With a mocked method though, you're not actually calling the method with the *exact* type parameters you specified. So you'll have to change the `Setup` call and change the fake mapping.

So to get around those problems you can do one of two things:

1. Change the method to use the overload of `Map` that returns a new instance.

   It doesn't look like you need to use the overload that takes two parameters, so you could tweak the method:

   ```
   var result = Mapper.Map<List<MenuItemQueryResult>(menuItems);
   ```

   And then in your test:

   ```
   Mapper.Setup(m => m.Map<List<MenuItem>, List<MenuItemQueryResult>>(It.IsAny<List<MenuItem>>())

   Mapper
       .Setup(m => m.Map<List<MenuItem>, List<MenuItemQueryResult>>(It.IsAny<List<MenuItem>>()))
       .Returns(menuItemQueryResult);
   ```
2. Change the test to mock the correct overload of `Map`.

   This is a little less intuitive, but possible. You'll have to provide a fake implementation of the `Map` method:

   ```
   Mapper
       .Setup(m => m.Map<List<MenuItem>, List<MenuItemQueryResult>>(It.IsAny<List<MenuItem>>(), It.IsAny<List<MenuItem>>()))
       .Callback((List<MenuItem> menuItems, List<MenuItemQueryResult> queryResults) =>
       {
           queryResults.AddRange(menuItemQueryResult);
       });
   ```

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I needed. 1)The mock mapping in the test is more strict with types (cannot expect List and IEnumerable to be equal 2) Overload of Map method must match between Mock and implementation. All pretty obvious now that I see whats happening.

Answer (score 1):

Your mock mapper is set up to return menuItemQueryResult but in you implementation you don't take the result of the Mapper.Map function. In my opinion you should use your mapper like this:

```
result = Mapper.Map(menuItems);
```

**Edit:**

In case you are using Automapper and it is correctly configured for the types:

```
result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuItem>, List<MenuItemQueryResult>>(menuItems);
```

Comment: That does not even compile

Comment: I assume you have written the mapper yourself, in that case change the implementation. If you are using AutoMapper instead, it should be : result = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<MenuItemQueryResult>>(menuItems); or check the details of the mapper you use.

Comment: That returns null in the test, but works on the actual site, which makes me think the problem is with my Moq set up